# Проблема при выполнении bash скрипта

Tags: bash, centos, sh

При выполнении скрипта (код ниже) получаю ошибку

```
: command not founda/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 5:
: command not founda/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 6:
: command not founda/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 7:
: command not founda/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 8:
'var/www/sitecom/data/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'var/www/sitecom/data/www/bash/download_yml.sh: line 9: `getfull() {
```

Команду выполняю под рутом. ОС - CentOS. Как можно исправить? Такой же скрипт на Debian 7 на другом сервере выполняется корректно.

```
#!/bin/bash
ver=0.0.5
dir_upload="/var/www/sitecom/data/www/site.com/uploads/catalog/_yml/"
curl_log="/var/www/sitecom/data/www/logs/yml.curl."
ctime=$(date "+%s");
mtime=3600;
i=0;

getfull() {
curl -L -q "http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml.php?upload=1&ssh=1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then "$(date "+%s"):result:load error"; exit; else echo "$(date "+%s"):get:load ok"; fi
};
doread() {
while read line
do
    IFS=';' read -a array <<< "$line"
    if [[ -n ${array[1]} ]]; then
    dostat "$dir_upload${array[0]}.xml.tmp"
    if [[ -n $rtime ]]; then
    curl -L -v -S --connect-timeout 30 -o "$dir_upload${array[0]}.xml.tmp" "${array[1]}" 2>>"$curl_log${array[0]}" &&
    /bin/mv -f "$dir_upload${array[0]}.xml.tmp" "$dir_upload${array[0]}.xml" &&
    curl -q "http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml_update_charset.php?id=${array[0]}&c=1" &&
    curl -q "http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml_update_charset.php?id=${array[0]}&k=1" &&
    curl -L -q "http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml.php?id=${array[0]}&load=1" &&
        # Инициализируем переменные перед началом цикла
        START=0
        COUNT=100
        EXIT=0
        ERRCOUNT=0
        # пока выполняется условие - крутим цикл
        while [[ $EXIT -eq 0 ]]
            do
            # раскоментировать след. строчку чтобы видеть процесс работы.
            # echo "`date` http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml.php?id=${array[0]}&work_yml=1&start=$START&count=$COUNT"
            # Получем ответ от сервера. 3 варианта: ок - увеличиваем счетчик, энд - завершаем цикл, или любой другой - увеличиваем счетчик ошибок)
            RESPONSE=$(curl -L -q "http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml.php?id=${array[0]}&work_yml=1&start=$START&count=$COUNT")
            case "$RESPONSE" in
                "end")  EXIT=1;;
                "ok")   START=$(($START+$COUNT));;
                *)      ERRCOUNT=$(($ERRCOUNT+1))
            esac
            # Если ошибок слишком много (больше 5) - прерываем цикл, чтобы не долбиться впустую
            if [[ $ERRCOUNT -ge 5 ]]; then
                EXIT=1
                echo "Error in request: http://h.site.com/engine/inc/catalog/cron/yml.php?id=${array[0]}&work_yml=1&start=$START&count=$COUNT"
            fi
            done
    res=$(echo $?)
    echo "$(date "+%s"):${array[0]}:$res"
    #echo "${array[0]}";
    #echo "${array[1]}";
    #echo "$line";
    i=$[i+1];
    else
    echo "$(date "+%s"):${array[0]}:locked"
    fi
    fi
done < $1
};
dostat() {
ftime=$(stat -c "%Y" $1 2>/dev/null)
if [[ -z $ftime ]]; then ftime=0; fi
diff=$(echo $ctime-$ftime|bc)
if [[ $diff -gt $mtime ]]; then
#echo "$(date "+%s"):stale:$diff";
rtime=1;
else
#echo "$(date "+%s"):locked:$diff";
rtime='';
fi
}
if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
echo "$(date "+%s"):fast:$1";
file="/var/www/sitecom/data/www/site.com/uploads/vendor_list.lst"
if [[ -e $file ]]; then dostat $file.tmp; if [[ -n $rtime ]]; then /bin/mv -f $file $file.tmp; doread $file.tmp; echo "$(date "+%s"):result:$i"; /bin/rm -f $file.tmp; else echo "$(date "+%s"):result:locked"; fi; else echo "$(date "+%s"):result:empty_fast"; fi
else
echo "$(date "+%s"):full:all";
file="/var/www/sitecom/data/www/site.com/uploads/vendors_list.lst"
getfull
sleep 5;
if [[ -e $file ]]; then dostat $file.tmp; if [[ -n $rtime ]]; then /bin/mv -f $file $file.tmp; doread $file.tmp; echo "$(date "+%s"):result:$i"; /bin/rm -f $file.tmp; else echo "$(date "+%s"):result:locked"; /bin/rm -f $file; fi; else echo "$(date "+%s"):result:empty"; fi
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменял через Notepad++ формат конца строки на "Преобразовать в UNIX-формат (LF)" и заработало!

Comment: Ваш скрипт раза в полтора как минимум сократить можно. Ну sh лучше использовать, если хочется переносимости, чем bash. Хотя по содержимому тут вообще python или perl — наше всё.